# UNIX script to send an alert mail if we didn't received files from the source before 12 am & to send an alert if the received files are zero byte

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm looking for ways to have an automated process that checks the number of files that we received everyday from source and file size as well. Currently, I am doing it manually by going to the location and to check it. This is tedious work since I'm doing this from time to time. Could someone guide me from here? It could be a shell script in a server that when I run, it will send an email to myself and others.

Also it should mention the file names if it received zero bytes at our end.

Files we are receiving everyday:

```
test_file1_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
test_file2_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
test_file3_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
test_file4_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
test_file5_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
test_file_20190919_20190918.mfst
sample_abc1_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
sample_abc2_20190919_20190918.txt.gz
sample_abc_20190919_20190918.mfst
```

I just want to confirm that we are receiving 9 files every day so that I need not check it manually every day, if not I need to inform the source team to send those files.

how can we check the date? 
We have script which will creates dated (yyyymmdd) directories under /folder1/folder2/folder3/ everyday and files will be received at today's dated directory.
EX: 
Path: /folder1/folder2/folder3/ 
20190918 20190919 --> Dated directoires for 18th and 19th September

Will the file names always be the same? 
Will they be the same but with different dates? 
Can they be completely different? 
The files pattern will remain same always but their date will change everyday and we will not receives files other the pattern i have mentioned.
For ex: 
test_file1_20190919_20190918.txt.gz (File will be received at 20190919 folder)
test_file1_20190918_20190917.txt.gz (File will be received at 20190918 folder)

What if you receive 10 files instead of 9? Is that a problem? 
What if the files are 9 but have an unexpected name, is that a problem?
yes, it will be problem.

Location: `/folder1/folder2/folder3/`

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: How do you check the file's age? Can we use the modification date? Will the file names always be the same? Have you started writing your script? What do you have so far?

Comment: If you happen to be doing this in the context of enterprise alerting, I recommend you tie this in with proper monitoring tools, NOT set up a custom email alert.  The Google SRE book is published free online (officially, not pirated) and contains an excellent chapter about monitoring and why email alerts as described in this question are generally a very bad idea.

Comment: Please answer the questions we ask you. We only ask to be able to help _you_. So I ask again: how can we check the date? Should we use the file name or the modification date the filesystem shows? Will the file names always be the same? Will they be the same but with different dates? Can they be completely different? What if you receive 10 files instead of 9? Is that a problem? What if the files are 9 but have an unexpected name, is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of ... running as cronjob?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
address="someone@your.company"
basepath=/folder1/folder2/folder3
err=0
expected=9
msg=''
subject='Filecheck'
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

null_files="$(find ${basepath}/${today} -type f -size 0)"
null_files="$(printf '    %s\n' $null_files )"

count=-1  # '.' counts.  One-off-error :-)
# if there are restricions on the filenames,
# replace this with an appropriate find-command
# and iterate over that instead...
for item in ${basepath}/${today}/* ; do
  ((count++))
done

[[ $count -eq $expected ]] && msg='[ OK ] Count of files as expected\n\n'
[[ $count -gt $expected ]] && \
  msg="[ERROR] Count of files too BIG: ${count}\n\n" ; err=1
[[ $count -lt $expected ]] && \
  msg="[ERROR] Count of files too SMALL: ${count}\n\n" ; err=1

if [[ -n "$null_files" ]]; then
  msg+='[ERROR] Found empty files:\n'
  msg+="$null_files"
  err=1
else
  msg+='[ OK ] No files with with 0 bytes found.'
fi

# echo -e "$msg"

[[ $err -ne 0 ]] && subject="[ERROR] $subject" || subject="[OK] $subject"
sendEmail -t "$address" -u "$subject" -m "$msg"
```

Comment: Thank you so much this scripting is working fine for me. I have one doubt now, if i didn't receive any files i should get count as zero but i am getting it as 1. So can you please help to resolve this?

Comment: I think the command is counting `.`, the current directory.  So we need to start with `count=-1`

Comment: Instead of counting the files can anybody help me to add  file patterns for above script? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Tried with Below script and it worked fine too

Kindly run the script after 12am

```
#!/bin/bash
d=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "1 days ago"`
#echo $d
echo "Below are list of files present"
find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" -newermt $d| sed "s/\.\///g"

count=`find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" -newermt $d| sed "s/\.\///g"| wc -l`
if [ $count -eq 9 ]
then
echo "Total Number of file exsists in present directory is $count"
zero_sizefile=`find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" -newermt $d -size 0| wc -l`
if [ $zero_sizefile > 0 ]
then
echo "Below are zero sized files"
find  . -type f -iname "*.txt" -newermt $d -size 0
else
echo "No files are zero sized files"
fi
else
echo "All files doesnt exists"
fi
```